# CSV file to a dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

So I'm working on an assignment and I'm trying to figure out a step where we're taking a csv file and converting it into a dictionary. One of my limitations is to not import csv. In searching other questions on here about converting a CSV file into a dictionary , all of them use import csv. For example, if my CSV file contains the following (first line is header):

```
"Headline","Newspaper", "Year Published", "Author"
"Crash", "New York Times", "2001", "Smith"
"Fire", "Washington Post", "2010", "Dudley"
"Addiction", "National Enquirer", "2008", "Kuhn"
```

How would I in turn be able to convert this data into a dictionary in Python without importing csv?

What I currently am working on, I have some pseudo code in there since I know what I want to carry out for those parts but am not 100% sure on how to do so since this is my first week using files and dictionaries together:

```
def read_file(filename):
    d={}
    with open(filename , 'r') as f:
        first_line = f.readline()
            for line in f:
                if line.strip().isdigit():
                # assign first string in line as key
                    #assign rest of strings in line as value to key in that line as a tuple
```

Comment: When you say "without importing csv", do you mean without using the `csv` module from the standard library?

Comment: SO Is not a code writing service. Please show your own code attempt for this and explain what difficulties you are having in your own code.

Comment: @idjaw I fully understand that and don't expect it to be.

Comment: @Nick Great. So where's your code? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can *transpose* the remaining lines after pulling the keys from the *header*:

```
with open("foo.csv") as f:
    # pull header line and split into keys
    keys = next(f).strip().split(",")
    # transpose remaining lines 
    values = zip(*(line.strip().split(",") for line in f))
    # zip keys and values and create a dict
    dct = dict(zip(keys, vals)
```

transposing will give you the elements column wise so they will match with each header key.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list containing dictionary items for each line, which is more of a JSON style formatting.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    keys = [val.strip().replace('"', '') for val in f.readline().split(',')]
    result = []
    for line in f:
        line = [val.strip().replace('"', '') for val in line.split(',')]
        result.append({key: val for key, val in zip(keys, line)})

>>> result
[{'Author': 'Smith',
  'Headline': 'Crash',
  'Newspaper': 'New York Times',
  'Year Published': '2001'},
 {'Author': 'Dudley',
  'Headline': 'Fire',
  'Newspaper': 'Washington Post',
  'Year Published': '2010'},
 {'Author': 'Kuhn',
  'Headline': 'Addiction',
  'Newspaper': 'National Enquirer',
  'Year Published': '2008'}]
```